# Is there a way to create a "Libraries We Use" page from composer?

Tags: php, web-services, composer-php

I am developing a proprietary php project, which is using several open source packages.

Is there a way to create a license page like this https://slack.com/libs/android directly via composer? Or do I have to copy all the licenses by hand?

Comment: You could iterate through the vendor folder and check the packages composer files. That would at least give you what type of licenses are defined, if any. You can also check if there's any LICENSE file. Regarding the name, the composer files only include the name in the `<vendor>/<package>` format. So for that, I would say, you can't (unless you extract the package name and convert it to camel case name yourself).

Answer (score 0):

You can find list of all installed packages in `vendor/composer/installed.json`. Usually they have a license info as a short name, like `MIT`.

If you want a full text of license, you should search for `LICENSE` or `LICENSE.md` file inside of root directory of dependency (e.g. `vendor/somevendor/somepackage/LICENSE.md`). Dependencies without such file may be unlicensed and using it may be illegal.

Answer (score 0):

The [PHP Legal Licenses](https://github.com/Comcast/php-legal-licenses) utility attempts to generate a license notice from `composer.lock`. I haven't used it myself, but it seems like it is fairly maintained and should work for your purposes.